# Change button background after pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button whose original color is red and I want it to change its color when in focus to green using tab key and when you press enter the color should come back to red.

```
 <div style="position: absolute; margin: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0">
 <input class="button calculator large top-right-border   transition" type="submit" />
 </div>


 .button.calculator{
 background:red;
 }

.button.calculator:focus{
 background:green;
 }
```

Comment: put your css in `<style></style>`, then it works.

Comment: Above is working but when I press enter button color remains green while I want it to be red after hitting enter once

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to acheive this.

Code

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
<button id="submit" onClick="functiong()">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
functiong() {
$("#parent").on('click', '#submit', function () {
     $("#submit").val("some value");
     $("#submit").attr("id", "some id");
     $("#submit").style.backgroundColor("#f47121");

   });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this, don't use `:focus` for css - changing the focused color can't be overriden with the original one.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6b5523o6/1/)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var toggleClasses = function(removeClass, addClass) {
    return function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.removeClass(removeClass);
        elem.addClass(addClass);
    };
};

$('#btn')
    .focus(toggleClasses('my-btn-red', 'my-btn-green'))

    .click(toggleClasses('my-btn-green', 'my-btn-red'))

    .focusout(toggleClasses('my-btn-green', 'my-btn-red'));
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn" class="my-btn-red">Button</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-btn-red {
    background: red;
}

.my-btn-green {
    background: green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Html:
    <body>
      <button class ="hai  hello">submit</button>
    </body>

CSS :

    .hai, .hello {
            background: red
        }
    .hello:focus {
            background: green
        }
Javascript :

$('document').ready(function() {
            $(".hai").click(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('hello')
            });
            $(".hai").focus(function() {
                $(this).addClass('hello')

            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use javascript or jQuery, use of :focus is not really the right way to do it.

You can use the javascript Char Codes to find the code of enter key and can fire an event.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rovp43o8/)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button.calculator').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('success');
    });

});

$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if ( event.which == 13){                        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.button.calculator').addClass('success');    
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin:0;">
     <input class="button calculator large top-right-border   transition" type="submit" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .button.calculator{
     background:red;
 }

.button.calculator.success{
     background:green;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="position: absolute; margin: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0">
  <input class="button calculator large top-right-border   transition" type="submit" />
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('.button.calculator').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('pressed');
  })
});
</script>

.button.calculator,
.button.calculator.pressed,
.button.calculator.pressed:focus {
  background:red;
}

.button.calculator:focus{
  background:green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use onFocus and onBlur property(Colar remain red after pressing).

This is JavaScript function.

Regards,